# Sample WebView application source code Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-webview, android-websettings

I'm working on an HTML5 based Android App, and I don't understand how to get WebView working. I was wondering if anyone could point me to a place where I can download the source code for an example application of this so I can modify it for my app, or at least reference it. It needs JavaScript support, and to open links in WebView, instead of in the Browser application, which I heard happens unless you change a setting. It will access local files only, not from the internet, but might later on interface with database systems, so it needs the Internet permission, but I think I understand how to add that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you too have a look on [Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/).
You can find everything to start a hybrid android app.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like a good solution! Is there by any chance like a GUI front-end to Cordova? An IDE that I can write my code in and have it automatically build and compile in Cordova for those platforms?

Comment: If you are targeting only for android then eclipse is fine. I have used the cordova plugin for Eclipse. You can also have a look on intel xdk(https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/tools).

Comment: That will work I think. I am going to support Tizen, Ubuntu Touch, Firefox OS, and Sailfish also, but I think I understand how to make HTML5 apps for those platforms, I just needed help with Android. I was just hoping for an IDE that was like based on Cordova or something. By any chance is there a Cordova Extension for Komodo Edit? It's the IDE that I normally use for my HTML5 development. Thank you!